# Add multiple prefabs at runtime with random scale?

Tags: random, unity-game-engine

I want to add prefabs to my scene at random positions at runtime. However only one prefab is added to the screen and then I get the error `Cannot cast from source type to destination type`. This is what I'm trying now:

```
private void generateLevel() {
    GameObject cube;
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        // Generate at random position in sphere
        cube = (GameObject) Instantiate(prefabPlanet, Random.onUnitSphere, Quaternion.identity); // Error

        // Random scale
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * Random.Range(1f, 10f);
    }
}
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: So you're saying the code you posted doesn't work? As far as I can tell it should randomize the scale of each cube, does it not? What value is Constantes.maxScale?

Comment: no, I tried it and for some reason I only get one object added to the scene. If I Instantiate directly (without saving it to a variable) I do get 8 planets. I'm trying a different way (I updated the question) but still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which is to instantiate the GameObject without a variable, by modifying the prefab before the instantiation.

I'm not very happy with this solution though, since it might be useful to save the object in a variable.

```
    for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        // Random Scale
        prefabPlanet.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1) * Random.Range(1f, 10f);

        // Random position
        Vector3 position = Random.onUnitSphere * Constants.radius;

        // Instatiate
        Instantiate(prefabPlanet, position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This script works fine for me, I'm not sure what your doing wrong. Unless its erroring on the random scale part due to Constantes.maxScale having an illegitimate value. Ensure errors and warnings are turned on in your console and check it for errors on that line.

Comment: Now I'm getting the error `cannot cast from source type to destination type`